# PHP character encoding issue Windows-1252 to UTF-8

Tags: php

I have a string that has a charset of Windows-1252, it is pulled from a email body using php's imap functions:

```
$string = 'Great job—and a great decision';
```

I then try convert it to utf-8 to insert it into our mysql database:

```
$utf8_encoded = iconv('Windows-1252', "UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $string);
```

The output comes looking like this:

```
echo $utf8_encoded;
Great jobâ€”and a great decision
```

It would be great to convert it to utf-8 without the hyphen causing issues. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

I can't always assume the charset will be Windows-1252, I need a solution that will work no matter what charset the email comes in with.

Comment: Is the database column you're storing the result in mysql actually utf-8? is the page you're outputting $utf8_encoded set to utf8 too? maybe the encoding isn't the issue

Comment: Good questions, I should have clarified, yes, the mysql database is set to utf-8 and so is the html page I echo the variable on.

Comment: What you are displaying as a string here is UTF8. The - is not a hyphen but the Unicode character Em Dash (U + 2014).

Comment: So, what is the issue? I'd also guess that you already have UTF-8. There's a function (`mb_encoding_detect()`?) which could help you guessing, but in the end try to get actual guarantees.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It's actually [`mb_detect_encoding( )`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php). But @jspit and you are right, the string is already UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the help, It does look like somewhere in my code I was double encoding it, thanks for leading me down that path to double check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was double encoding the string when extracting the email earlier in the code. Problem solved :)